# sending multiple files in python

Tags: python

I'm new with python, I am trying the following, I have two calsess: `Server.py` and  `Client.py` I want to send all the files that exists in server directory to some directory at the client side. i.e

> C:\ServerDir\file1.txt
>
> C:\ServerDir\file2.txt
>
> C:\ServerDir\file3.txt...

would go to:

> D:\ClientDir\file1.txt
>
> D:\ClientDir\file2.txt
>
> D:\ClientDir\file3.txt...

For now I can send single file,  **Server.py**:

```
   import socket                   # Import socket module

port = 60000                    # Reserve a port for your service.
s = socket.socket()             # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname()     # Get local machine name
s.bind((host, port))            # Bind to the port
s.listen(5)                     # Now wait for client connection.

print ('Server listening....')

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
    print ('Got connection from', addr)
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print('Server received', repr(data))

    filename='C:\\Users\\Desktop\\File.txt'
    f = open(filename,'rb')
    l = f.read(1024)
    while (l):
       conn.send(l)
       print('Sent ',repr(l))
       l = f.read(1024)
    f.close()

    print('Done sending')
    conn.send('Thank you for connecting'.encode())
    conn.close()
```

**Client.py:**

```
    import socket                   # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()             # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname()     # Get local machine name
port = 60000                    # Reserve a port for your service.

s.connect((host, port))
s.send("Hello server!".encode())

with open('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Python\\gg.txt', 'wb') as f:
    print ('file opened')
    while True:
        print('receiving data...')
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print('data=%s', (data))
        if not data:
            break
        # write data to a file
        f.write(data)

f.close()
print('Successfully get the file')
s.close()
print('connection closed')
```

I have tried to loop over all files in server side like:

```
 for file in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\'):
    filename = 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\'+file
```

but it sends only the first file.

Answer (score 1):

The critical bit is - how do you know a file ended? In your current implementation, if the connection ends, so does the file (and then you have a closed socket, so no chance for a next file).

There are two solutions:

- Simple: Make the client open a new connection for each file (i.e. move stuff into the loop); if you get an instant broken connection, maybe that's the end of everything
- Better: Have the server send the file size before the file itself. Have the client only write data to a file till the size is correct, then start working on a new file.

Of course, you still have an issue about how the server will know what file names to assign the incoming files. You could put those into the "header" that by now likely consists of filename :)

If you're wondering, this is exactly (well, close enough) what HTTP does. Each file has headers, then an empty line, then a stream of bytes whose length was communicated before by the `Content-Length` header. After that, the connection can be reused for the next file. If `Content-Length` is missing, the agent will read till the connection is broken (and the next file will need to establish a new connection).